# Second reading of zachor at mincha

Tags: torah-service, mincha-afternoon-prayer, parshat-zachor

Many shuls read zachor a second time on Shabbos Zachor, either before or after mincha, to allow people who missed the first reading to hear it.  In all the cases I've heard, this is without a bracha.

Another procedure would be plausible to me, but I've never heard of anyone doing it.  Why not do it as part of the normal Mincha reading?  Take out two Sifrei Torah, merge two of the normal Mincha aliyot into one, and for the third aliyah read Zachor.  This would have the advantage of saying brachot before and after reading Zachor.

Are there any places that do this?  What are the objections to reading in this way?

Comment: I don't understand. Zakhor isn't the reading for Mincha. How could you say a blessing on it?

Comment: @DoubleAA if you make it the 3rd aliya?  It's not obvious to me how precisely the is fixed.  For instance I've heard of people extending mincha through the entire parsha to help people traveling from America to Israel "catch up" when Yom Tov Sheni is Shabbos.  That's easier to accept because it's at least the right parsha, but maybe making one of the 3 aliyot from another place is also allowed.  I don't know.

Comment: I once asked a Rav what the procedure was to do Zachor in Shabbat Mincha, and he told me that I should merge the regular reading into 2 aliyot, and read zachor for the 3rd aliya.

Comment: @Menachem I rarely change a rav, but, I will make an unusual exception in this case. I don't care to know the rav's name, but I would like to know his source for this opinion.

Comment: From my recollecti0n, the practice of public Torah reading on Shabbat afternoon has a markedly different reason than the ones done on Mon. & Thurs. It is not related to Ezra's concern of going 3 days or more without Torah reading (as we heard one in the morning). Thus, it's possible, that any extra reading or even taking out  separate Torah for Mincha may constitute *torach tzibbur*. That may be in addition to the idea that the reading of "zachor" is meant to be as maftir, which would cause the requirement for a bracha as it is an "aliya" (Separate discussion as to WHY that is.)