# Parshas Zachor during Mincha reading?

Tags: torah-reading, parshat-zachor

I was told about a synagogue where they had a second reading of Parshas Zachor during the reading for Mincha with the following procedure: The first two aliyos are read normally, and for the third aliya (people are told to be mechaven for Zachor) the blessing is said and the normal portion is read, then the Sefer is rolled from where it is to Zachor, the reading is continued there and the final blessing is said. This is done during the regular Mincha. Supposedly, this procedure is approved by Rav Avigdor Neventzal, the Rav of the Old City of Jerusalem.

I find this procedure very difficult to accept, and question if it really was said by Rav Neventzal. This approach is directly against two halachos in Shulchan Aruch:

> [Orach Chaim 144:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.144.1?lang=bi&lang2=en)
>
> מדלגין בנביא ואין מדלגין בתורה מפרשה זו לפרשה אחרת והני מילי בשני עניינים דחיישינן שמא תתבלבל דעת השומעים
>
> We skip in the Prophets, but we do not skip in the Torah from one section to another section. And these words are regarding two subjects where we are worried that perhaps the mind of the listeners will be confused,
>
> 144:3
>
> אין גוללין ס"ת בצבור מפני כבוד הצבור ואם אין להם אלא ס"ת אחד והם צריכים לקרות בשני עניינים גוללים וידחה כבוד הצבור:
>
> It is not proper to roll the Torah scroll in the presence of the congregation, so as to honor the congregation. And if they only have a single Torah scroll and they have to read two portions they may roll, and they defer the honor of the congregation.

To clarify the second issue, while (apparently) some of the congregation (let's even say some of the men) still need to hear Zachor, the congregation as a whole does not. How is the honor of the congregation pushed off for the need of the individuals? (If the only ones who need to hear Zachor are women, that can only make the issue worse.)

Can anyone 1) explain how this is not in conflict with both or either of these halachos, or 2) confirm that any notable Rabbi has ruled to follow this procedure?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80873/19563

Comment: I'm not sure what your question from 144:3 is. Given that you can't have more than three aliyot at mincha, there is no way to do this procedure without rolling, so it becomes the equivalent of having only one sefer

Comment: @joelk the tzibbur isn't mochel for a minority (certainly not a minority of safek obligated (if we're being generous) people and/or those who couldn't bother to come to the original reading). What the minority do on their own time is their business. The question is sound.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a question of metziut, no? A shul of young married husbands could be quite willing to wait for an additional few minutes so that their very frum wives get the chance to hear parashat zachor

Comment: @Joel I'm not sure this mechilla is an active process at all (we don't let a tzibbur read from just a shemot scroll even if they don't mind), but anyway what are the chances all men have wives there but couldn't have them there in the morning? And who said you only need a simple majority of the tzibbur to be mochel?

Comment: There probably were extenuating circumstances that forced this congregation into a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Against the Shulchan Aruch on two accounts seems to me worse than "suboptimal."